# How to bring overlapping border to front when hovered?

Tags: css, border, overlap

I have several divs arranged horizontally next to each other with a black border of 1px. They overlap on left/right sides. I don't want to add margin as that would cause the border to be 2px when elements are next to each other.

When a user hover's over the border changes to white color. The issue is that the second element(and others after first element) have their left border hidden behind the previous element and it appears that the left border doesn't change color. How can I make the hovered element be on top? I tried z-index with no change at all.

```
.upcoming a:before{
    display:block;
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:184px;
    height:277px;
    border:1px solid #666;
}

.upcoming a:hover:before{
    border-color:#CCC;
}
```

(I am using :before for different reasons than border - overlapping box shadow)

Edit: added picture

In this screenshot "the fall" poster is hovered an it is zoomed in quite a bit too. Notice that the left border is not lighter color(because it is overlapped by the fists border).

[image]

Comment: could you add a picture or a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Added a screenshot, see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have already tried, I think `z-index` is the best option here. It is designed purely for being able to manage the z-position of each element.

See this jsfiddle for example:

http://jsfiddle.net/CjYa9/1/

Perhaps you were doing something different.

Comment: It may be an issue with:before or absolute positioning but it simply does not work in this case...

Comment: @DominicM Can you replicate in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I found that it was the :before element that was causing borders to overlap due to limited space so now that I fixed that I cant seem to get borders to overlap at all(position relative or absolute causes all elements to disappear). z-index might wok now if I manage to get borders to overlap :)

Comment: Looks like it is not possible to achieve what I want without using a different approach to box shadow. z-index would otherwise be correct for what I want so accepting.

Comment: @Curt it seems that this solution doesn't work when using a box-shadow. It doesn't overlap. Any workarounds?

**- Update:** I found this answer which solved my issue with the z-index & box-shadow. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208200/css-box-shadow-overlapping-issue-z-index