# CSS Box/shadow overlapping issue z-index

Tags: html, css, css-float

Please take a look at the code snippet: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JItLa

I'm trying to show 2 rows of blocks with different amount of items in a row.
The hover event should reveal the CSS shadow, but there is a problem: the right border of the shadow is overlapped with the next block. 
You would say the possible solution here is to use display:inline-block which leaves the gaps between the blocks, but I don't need the gaps. The blocks should stay sticky to each other but the right shadow should overlap the next block onhover.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px
}
.tile,
.tile2 {
  float: left;
  background: #f2f2f2
}
.tile {
  width: 25%
}
.tile2 {
  width: 33.3%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd
}
.tile:hover,
.tile2:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 190, .75), 0 0 23px 1px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 190, .75), 0 0 23px 1px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 190, .75), 0 0 23px 1px #000
}
.header {
  padding: 20px 0px 10px;
  text-align: center
}
.clear {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="header">some text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="header">some text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="header">some text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="header">some text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tile2">
    <div class="header">some text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile2">
    <div class="header">some text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile2">
    <div class="header">some text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

How is that possible?

There is another problem here: when I add the border between the blocks the last blocks moves to the next line which is not OK. See the 2nd row in the example given above.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add a **[`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)** to the element on hover.

Additionally, the element also has to be positioned in order for the **[`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)** property to work. Therefore add `position:relative` too.

> [**9.9.1 Specifying the stack level: the 'z-index' property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index)
>
> z-index: Applies to: positioned elements
>
> Each box has a position in three dimensions. In addition to their horizontal and vertical positions, boxes lie along a "z-axis" and are formatted one on top of the other. Z-axis positions are particularly relevant when boxes overlap visually. This section discusses how boxes may be positioned along the z-axis.

**[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/orKue)** - it works now.

```
.tile:hover, .tile2:hover {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

To address your second issue, the elements are appearing on a new line because their widths do not add up, as it is `1px` off due to the border.

`33.3%` + `33.3%` + `33.3%` + `1px` != `100%`

You have a few different options:

- Use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to subtract `1px` from the width - `width: calc(33.3% - 1px)`
- Change the box model to include the border in the element's width calculation - **[`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)**

If you choose to use **[`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)**, you need appropriate vendors/prexes if you want support across all browsers. I would use something like:

```
.tile2 {
    width: 33.3%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[**Updated Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FsaGv) using **[`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)**.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. I was playing with z-index previously, but it did not work for me. It seems the 'position:relative' rocks. But I don't understand how it works. I would appreciate greatly if you  could explain the way it works. Don't want just to copy/paste the solution but want understand its origin. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Andreas Alright, I updated my answer. [According to W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) the `z-index` property **only** applies to positioned elements in the DOM. As for the reason why, I can only guess its because the element doesn't exist in 3 dimensions, as it's not positioned. Thus, the `z-index` has no effect.

Comment: Thank YOU very much. I tried the z-index alone and of course it didn't work. You just solved a lot of problems around here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS, if you do not need the gap between the divs.

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0px;
}
.tile,
.tile2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
.tile:hover,
.tile2:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.header {
  font-size: 12px;
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing a little additional information to `@Josh Crozier`'s answer here -- I would still consider their answer correct.

If you do not set the `background-color` or other `background` styling to the item you want on top with the `z-index`, it won't matter.

FYI - if my `CSS` below looks weird, I'm using less.js for parts of it.

```
nav {
    .flex-column;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: fit-content;
    /**Could alternatively add a background-color here in lieu or 
    addition to the footer element below**/
}

footer {
    height: 1.5rem;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: var(--background); //If this is not set, then they still show the crossing box-shadows
    .flex-row;
    .box-shadows;
}

.box-shadows {
    box-shadow: var(--boxShadow);
    -webkit-box-shadow: var(--boxShadow);
    -moz-box-shadow: var(--boxShadow);
}

:root {
    --background: #008080;
    --foreground: #ffffff;
    --boxShadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #000000;
}
```