# Overlapping border hover

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs arranged vertically with 1px, overlapping borders. When I hover over the bottom div, its whole border is highlighted. However, when I hover over the top or middle divs, the bottom portion of the border is obscured by the div below. How can I fix this? I tried setting `z-index` on the hover style, but it doesn't appear to force the div above the other siblings.

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.25em;
  width: 100px;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: -1px;
}
.box:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.box:hover {
  border-color: #000;
  z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Top</div>
<div class="box">Middle</div>
<div class="box">Bottom</div>
```

Comment: Why are you overlapping the borders if you don't want them to overlap? I presume the very reason for your overlap is to hide the extra pixel between elements... so that's precisely what you get.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208200/css-shadow-overlapping-issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161796/overlap-the-image-on-hover

Comment: also your `margin-top: -1px;` should just go in the `.box` properties, there is no need for listing all the children differently here.

Comment: @leigero I used the different *margin-top*s because I was having trouble getting the borders to overlap. Using  `position: relative` seems to fix that as well.

Comment: I would do it without the nth-child http://jsfiddle.net/ookb997e/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple, just add `position:relative;` to `.box` (you already have the `z-index` on `hover`) to establish the ***stacking context*** required for it to work the way you need it.

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    /* rest of the styles */
}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/L6sysroh/

Read more on [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `position: relative;` in order for `z-index` to work as it applies only to positioned elements.

http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/